# (Bootstrap) Modify characteristics of default buttons?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So i currently have a grid setup, using the `.col-md-3` class for 4 buttons across the page. I want to change both the color and the sizing of the buttons. I know that changing the core Boostrap CSS is generally frowned upon, so I made a separate CSS file but my changes keep seeming to be overwritten.

How would I go about changing the color and sizing for the buttons?

For reference, it currently looks like this:

[image]

I'm also trying to increase the height of the buttons for use above a certain screen size breakpoint, how should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the getbootstrap.com page, customize section, there are no options for it? If not you can download the sass version and then change/ compile as you please.   Also for your last bit about button height, use the media queries bootstrap gives you, change the  pixel thresholds or creatr your own.

If you still want to maintain a separate sheet, make sure you include it in your html AFTER the default bootstrap.css

If that doesnt work, use your browser dev tools (f12) and fiddle around

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I knew about the customize section, I just wasn't aware it was that customizable! I still would like to use a separate stylesheet to keep track of custom changes and not have to worry about core Bootstrap updates, among other reasons. I definitely declared the stylesheet after the others which is why I was very confused about why my changes weren't showing. Any thought's? Also, for your bit about button height, could you give me some insight on how to do that?

Comment: I would first try clearing your cache. Then i would try to use your developer tools( press f12 in any browser). Bootstrao may use !important on some of their css so you might have to declare it on yours also.

Comment: As for your buttons, google is your friend. Search "media queries css"

Comment: Will do, thanks for calling out my laziness lol. Was a simple error causing most of the problems (it always is...).